# I'm having trouble converting a Raster to an Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, raster, gdal

I'm currently having some trouble converting a raster to an array. Ultimately I would like to convert a raster from an integer to a float32 so that I can run a gdal_calc however, I could not change the type properly in order to do this.

SO, I would appreciate any help that someone could provide. Here is my script, very short.

```
import gdal
import numpy as np
import math
import osgeo
import os
import scipy


# Open Rasters 

hvRaster = gdal.Open("C:\\Users\\moses\\Desktop\\Calc_Test\\IMG-HV-ALOS2110871010-160611-HBQR1.5RUA.img")
vhRaster = gdal.Open("C:\\Users\\moses\\Desktop\\Calc_Test\\IMG-VH-ALOS2110871010-160611-HBQR1.5RUA.img")


# Get Raster Band

hvRasterBand = hvRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
vhRasterBand = vhRaster.GetRasterBand(1)

# Convert Raster to Array

hvArray = np.array(hvRaster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
vhArray = np.array(vhRaster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

print hvArray
print vhArray
```

Thank you in advance,

Moses

Answer (score 2):

The method ReadAsArray() will create a numpy.ndarray with a dtype of the raster dataset. Your goal is to transform an integer dtype to a float32. The simplest way to do this is to use the [astype()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method for ndarray.

```
# Convert Raster to Array

hvArray = hvRaster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)
vhArray = vhRaster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: *I'm the author of the following library.*

[lidario.Translator](https://lidario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api/translator.html) can help you to transform a **raster into a point cloud** (np.array):

```
import lidario as lio
    
# Create a Translator object which will take a tif file and return a np.array
translator = lio.Translator("geotiff", "np")
    
# Translate the tif file and get the np.array
point_cloud = translator.translate("/path/to/file.tif")
```

Lidario use GDAL under the hood.

Comment: You *must disclose affiliation in the post* when linking to something you're affiliated with. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)